# Gboard option to display pronounciations above autosuggestions

Tags: gboard, dictionary, text-prediction

I wonder whether it would be possible to install a gboard plugin (that could be activated, or disactivated), that showed IPA (or other spellings system) pronunciation above spellings for autosuggestions.

This would enable users that understood words by visualizing what they heard in their own spelling systems, to have suggestions for correct spellings, and also suggestions for correct pronounciations, given that the pronunciation system they use in their native tongue might differ from the one implemented.

It would also allow users who were familiar to varying degrees to visualize sounds spellings (aka pronounciations), without disturbing others by having them played out.

They would learn quickly.

It would also be a great tool for kids and adults learning foreign languages.

How can I make this functionality available in Android Gboard?

When will it be available?

Is anyone willing to implement it?

Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge GBoard has no extension/add-on system. So you can use it or switch to a different keyboard of your choice.